# How do I pass File Stream to Tesseract

Tags: tesseract

In all the examples I've seen, including the one I have working, you interact with Tesseract using a file path.

However, since I need to use Tesseract in a web service, the user will pass a Base64Encoded stream to the web service method, not a file path string.

Thus far, I have not been able to find the right method to let me use a ByteArrayOutputStream or a File object.

The file path (string) is read using: pixRead(), but this method doesn't work with a File object or ByteArrayOutputStream.

--

I also tried the tess4j library as an alternative since it uses a File object (I tried every released version in testing) but only got a crashed JVM. Others got that message also (but no resolution) so now I'm back at just regular Tesseract.

--

Would anyone please give me a code example of how to pass a File Object or a ByteArrayOutputStream to Tesseract so I can read the image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 options to avoid using file path:

- **command line**: tesseract executable accept image from sdtin. You can try something like this: `curl
  "http://d2jaiao3zdxbzm.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/figure-65.png"
  | tesseract - -`.
- **tesseract API**: you can set image data to tesseract engine with [`SetImage`](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/59cd71660920dbbf222b5e1ba34d476ee6258512/src/api/baseapi.h#L343) directly. I am not familiar with java but looks like it is also available in tess4j as [TessBaseAPISetImage](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/docs-4.3/).

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get Tess4j to work from a web service running inside the IDE, but get the same crash as others reported when running from a built JAR file.

Comment: First: report it to tess4j project. Maybe also try to asked at tesseract user forum - there are some java developers.

Comment: I figured it out. You have to make sure you have the path to the tessdata directory and also (on the mac) export the environment variable "LC_ALL" with the value "C".

Comment: Hi, @Morkus I am also struck up at the same level, did you find any solution to pass byte steam to tesseract?

Comment: For me, exporting the LC_ALL environment variable (per my posting above yours) solved my problem. If you describe what you're doing in more detail, I'll try to help.